# Creating objects from text file input

Tags: java, object

I'm still very new to java. I am trying to create an array of objects from a text file. The text file has a list of names, and using these names, I'm trying to create objects. This is the method I've created to create the objects from the text file input. It gives an error when compiled. I'm not sure where I've done wrong.

```
   public boolean createObjects(PersonNames2[] person) throws Exception
   {
       boolean found = false;
       int position = 0;
       if(canCreateObjects() == true)
       {
           for(int i = 0; i < persons.length && !found; i++)
           {
               if(persons[i] == null)
               {
                   position = i;
                   found = true;
               }
           }
           Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
           while(reader.hasNext())
           {
               person[position] = new PersonNames2();
               position++;
           }
           reader.close();
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
```

Comment: Share your compilation error....

Comment: parameter is `person` and your are using `persons`

Comment: I get this error
PersonNames2.java:27: error: array dimension missing
        PersonNames person[] = new Person[]; 
                                           ^
1 error

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Lol....welcome back....have not seen u here for sometime...im also not so active:p

Comment: @Rustam good pick with a naked eye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this working. Thanks! Here is the working code.

```
    public static List<Person> loadPersons(String path) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Adding " +line);
            persons.add(new Person(line));
        }

        return persons; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> error: array dimension missing PersonNames person[] = new Person[];

That's clearly telling that you are failed to give the size of your array.

You need to write

```
PersonNames person[] = new Person[size]; // For ex : 10 or any X
```

Array's are fixed in size and you need to tell the size of it while declaring/initializing  it self.

**Update:**

Since you are reading data from a file and no idea about the length of array, better to choose [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of array. Size of the [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) increases over the time you add elements to it.

Comment: If I were to create a an array with a set size i would just PersonNames person = new Person[5].
How can I go about doing this if I'm using the no of lines in the file as the size

Comment: @MichelleAshwini Updated my answer :) Hope that helps

Comment: @SURESHATTA That makes sense. I'm trying that out now. Will get back on it.

Comment: I thought you were passing array as argument in function boolean createObjects(PersonNames2[] person) so why need to initialize ???

Answer (score 0):

If you are new in Java, than this tiny [GitHub](https://github.com/kjkrol/jackson-mappers-wrapper) project could be a nice set of hints for you.